# Normalizer for CSV row in which it records the first two rows. Then running a Junit test

Tags: java, csv, junit, normalization, junit4

I am trying to write a normalizer for this CSV file that has two columns. A BIN( which is a number in the first row) and a BBL( which is a String in the second row). I then wrote a JUnit test( seen under this normalizer). When I run the Junit test I get a Method 'Initialization Error'not found. Opening the test class. Can someone please help me.

The CSV looks like this:

```
BIN    boro
10001  Finnacial 
...
```

### Normalizer

```
      package bah.placebook.data.normalization.impl;

      import java.util.HashMap;

      import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
      import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

      import bah.placebook.data.models.Building;
      import bah.placebook.data.normalization.util.LatLongUtil;


  @Component
   public class Neighborhood_Normalizer_CSV extends BuildingDataCSVNormalizer {




  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Neighborhood_Normalizer_CSV.class);


     @Override

      public String getDatasetId(){
        return"Neighborhood_data";
    }

      @Override
    protected Building outputNormalizedRow(String[] csvRow){
        Building building = new Building();



    HashMap<String, Integer> columns = getColumnNames();


                 try {
                        building.setBin(Integer.parseInt(csvRow[columns.get("bin")]));
                         }  
                  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                         log.error("Unable to extract BIN number",e);
                        return null;
                    }

                try {

            String bbl = csvRow[columns.get("boro")] + csvRow[columns.get("block")] +                               

           csvRow[columns.get("lot")];

           building.setBblNumber(Integer.parseInt(bbl.trim()));
   } 

        catch (NumberFormatException f) {

        log.error("Unable to extract BBL number",f);
   }
    return building;
    }

    }
```

### JUnit Test

```
package bah.placebook.data.normalization.impl;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

import bah.placebook.data.normalization.NormalizationManager;
import bah.placebook.data.normalization.exceptions.UnknownDataSetException;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/spring/application-context.xml")
public class NeighborhoodNormalizerTest {

 @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

  @Autowired
  private NormalizationManager nManager;

  @Test

   public void normalize() throws UnknownDataSetException, IOException {

    File testData = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:data/nieghborhood.csv");
    File normalizedData = folder.newFile();
    try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(testData);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(normalizedData)) {
      nManager.normalizeDataset("nieghborhood",is , os);
    }

    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(new  FileInputStream(normalizedData)))) {
      String line = reader.readLine();
      while(line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace of the Initialization Error.

Comment: Please try to format your code in a nice way. We like to help you, but it is easier for us if you use a proper formatting.

Comment: can you pls submit spring/application-context.xml thx